# html5 localstorage error safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, local-storage

My website have this error when I'm on ios safari browsing:

> "QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add
>   something to storage that exceeded the quota."

The error is on the next line:

```
localStorage.setItem('abcdf', 'true');
```

I've been researching this problem on the web and always indicates that is when I am in private browsing, but in my case, it is not.
I'm on default browser, not on private browsing.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What the issue is

The `localStorage` size is limited to a relatively small size (a few MB tops). In Safari this exception occurs in two cases:

- In private browsing mode *no* localStorage access is allowed so calling `localStorage.set` will always cause this error.
- In regular browsing this exception happens when the quota is exceeded - that is, either the localStorage contains too many things. Web browsers make no guarantees about the actual size of `localStorage`

### Fixing it

The simplest solution except storing less things on the client-side is to use something like `IndexedDB` which has much much higher quotas. It also performs better because it performs non-blocking io.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The problem is that I'm sure the localStorage could not be filled. I'm Just keeping a couple of variables in it.